# Minify topojson files to their greatest or combine them in one

Tags: leaflet, minify, geojson, qgis, topojson

I am building a leaflet map displaying Taiwan census data. There are many layers which slows the loading of the site a lot. I would like to make the loading of the website more efficient.

The data for each layer is now stored in topojson format and through QGIS and mapshaper I have already simplified the geometry and the number of digits for lat/lng to further minimize the size of these files. Yet, the map is still very slow to load.

Any other ideas as to what I could do with the topojson files?

Here is a link to the website (it is in Chinese): http://140.112.64.66/website/taiwancensus/#legend

Comment: **topojson** format is the lightest format to store the spatial information. If even the topojson files have larger size, you probably need to use some **spatial server** like **geoserver** or you can use [cartodb](https://cartodb.com/). Upload your dataset there and they will provide you link, you can embed in your map

Comment: Is there maybe a way to load the topojson files only when they are queried/toggled by the user? -- Instead of having them load all at once when the website starts?

Comment: yes, ofcourse for that you need to get **extent** of map for example when the user ends up the map **panning** or **zooming**, **intersect** the extent with database (you must have each topojson extent in database), and those who intersect with the extent get them and add to map